# Huge noise spikes when using WIFI

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wifi-configuration

I have a router setup in my **apartment** and for the past 3 month's it has been working fine.  However, recently I've been having a hard time connecting to it, and when I do, it will drop my connection occasionally (Maybe a 10 second drop every 15 minutes).  Using my computer's wireless diagnostic tool, I see that right before my Internet drops, there is a huge Noise spike.  See the diagrams below.  Does anyone have any suggestions of what could be wrong or how I can try to fix this?  Below I've included what I think may be useful information:

[image]

[image]

**Possibly useful information**

- There are only **two people** using my router (it's protected with a strong password)
- The router is a really good one (ASUS N66U I believe)
- The router is using 2.4GHz (Should I switch to 5Ghz?)
- The Internet connection should be 100Mbps download
- There are about **10 other Internet networks** around me (from my neighbors)
- My apartment is of average size and contains 3 rooms.
- The router is in the kitchen and I connect using my 2013 Macbook Air from an adjoining bedroom
- The only other appliances being used in the house are a refridgerator, a sleeping iPhone and Android phone, a turned off TV, a fan and some lights

Let me know if there are any more details that would be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: The noise rises exponentially for a time before it kills your connection. Can you tell us how long it (time) is from start to end of the blue spike? The graph doesn't have a labeled X axis ):

Comment: Maybe 10 seconds...Definitley under a minute

Comment: Microwave oven interference?

Comment: Microwave is not in use

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to try and find out what that very clean noise spike is. Can you pin it down to a time of day or night? Weekdays or weekends?

Also, do your neighbors have this problem to? I would talk to them (if they aren't hostile to other people) and see if they are getting this too or not. Try and winnow it down to the problem.

I admit this is going to be alot of work, but if you find "it" you will have the real root cause of the problem.